# Show that the mle of $\theta$ is the median of a sample

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

The double exponential distribution is 
$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x-\theta|},\ \ \ \ \ \ -\infty < x < \infty$$
We are looking at an i.i.d. sample of size $n = 2m + 1$. I would like to show that the maximum likelihood of $\theta$ is the median of the sample. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that your values are stored from the lowest to the highest, i.e.
$$ x_1 \leq x_2 \leq ... \leq x_{m-1} \leq x_m \leq x_{m+1} ...\leq x_{2m+1} $$

the likelihood is given by:
$$ L(x_1,...,x_{2m+1},\theta) = f(x_1,\theta)...f(x_{2m+1},\theta) = \frac{1}{2^{2m+1}} \exp{\left(- \sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} \vert x_k - \theta \vert \right)}$$

Therefore, the log-likelihood is:

$$ l(x_1,...,x_{2m+1},\theta) = \ln( L(x_1,...,x_{2m+1},\theta) ) = - (2m+1)\ln2 - \sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} \vert x_k - \theta \vert $$

You want the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the likelihood, i.e. the value of $\theta$ that minimizes the sum $g(\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} \vert x_k - \theta \vert$.

We want to get rid of the absolute values because we know they are not easy to differentiate. We now that $\vert x_k - \theta \vert = x_k - \theta$ if $\theta \leq x_k $, and  $\vert x_k - \theta \vert =\theta - x_k$ if $\theta \geq x_k $.

We know that $$ x_1 \leq x_2 \leq ... \leq x_{m-1} \leq x_m \leq x_{m+1} ...\leq x_{2m+1} $$

so we know that $\theta$ is necessarily:

a) either in the interval $]-\infty, x_1]$;

b)either in the interval $[x_1,x_2]$;

c) either in the interval  $[x_2,x_3]$;

etc

y)  either in the interval  $[x_{2m},x_{2m+1}]$;

z) either in the interval $[x_{2m+1},+\infty[$.

So basically you have to study $g(\theta)$ on each of these intervals, and find where the minimal value of $g(\theta)$ is reached.

Let's begin by the first and the last case:
if $\theta \in ]-\infty, x_1]$, we have $\theta \leq x_k$ for **all** $k$, because the values are stored from the lowest to the highest. Therefore $\vert x_k - \theta \vert = x_k - \theta$ for all $k$, and

$$ g(\theta) =\sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} ( x_k - \theta ) =  \sum_{k=1}^{2m+1}  x_k - (2m+1) \theta$$

clearly, this function is linear with a negative slope $-(2m+1)$. Therefore, it is decreasing on the interval $\theta \in ]-\infty, x_1]$. On this interval, $g(\theta)$ is minimal for $\theta = x_1$.

Conversely, on the interval $[x_{2m+1},+\infty[$ you will find that $g(\theta)$ is linear with a positive slope, and therefore is minimal on this interval for $\theta = x_{2m+1}$.

Now, we are stuck with the other intervals. Suppose that we study $g(\theta)$ for $\theta \in [x_j,x_{j+1}]$, where $j$ is an integer between $1$ and $2m$.

We know that $x_j \leq \theta \leq x_{j+1}$, therefore $\theta \geq x_k$ for all $k \in \{1,...,j\}$, and $\theta \leq x_k$ for all $k \in \{j+1,...,2m+1\}$. This allows us to get rid of the absolute values:

$$ g(\theta) =\sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} \vert x_k - \theta \vert = \sum_{k=1}^{j}(\theta - x_k) + \sum_{k=j+1}^{2m+1}( x_k - \theta) = (2j-(2m+1))\theta + ...  $$

where "$...$" is a constant term that does not depend on $\theta$. So, once again, your function is linear with a slope equal to $2j-(2m+1)$, which is negative if $j \in \{1,...m\}$ and positive if  $j \in \{m+1,...2m\}$.

So $g(\theta)$ is decreasing on $[x_1,x_2] ,...,[x_m,x_{m+1}]$ and then increasing on $[x_{m+1},x_{m+2}], ... [x_{2m},x_{2m+1}]$.

Here we are! We have shown that the function is decreasing on all the intervals until $x_{m+1}$, and increasing on all the intervals after. Therefore, it is minimal for $\theta = x_{m+1}$, which is the median value of your sample.

Comment: Answers leaving to the OP something to do are allright in general but in the present case, I am not sure this post does not leave untouched the part they have a problem with.

Comment: OK, I will try to get further if I have the time to do so.

Comment: @R.Bourgeon But how can I find this maximum value, since a function $g(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable, I can't simply take the derivative and set equal to zero?

Comment: You can distinguish several cases. Since you have $2m+1$ values, you have to study the function $g(\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} \vert x_k - \theta \vert $ on $2m+2$ intervals, that are $]-\infty,x_1], [x_1,x_2], ... [x_{2m},x_{2m+1}], [x_{2m+1},+\infty[$. The function has a minimum on each of these intervals. You just have to take the lowest of these minima, and it will be obtained for $\theta = x_{m+1}$ (which is the median of your sample).

Comment: @R.Bourgeon I'm sorry I don't follow. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: OK. I will edit my answer, and put in it what I told you in the previous comment, and elaborate it. You will see that it's not that difficult.

Comment: @Di-lemma it's done! It's pretty heavy to redact such kind of reasoning. Hope you understand now.

Comment: A simpler approach is to note that $g$ is continuous everywhere and that $g'(\theta)$ at each $\theta$ not in the set $X=\{x_i\mid1\leqslant i\leqslant2m+1\}$ is equal to the size of $X\cap(\theta,\infty)$ minus the size of $X\cap(-\infty,\theta)$. Thus, assuming the $x_i$s are distinct and caling $u$ their median, one sees directly that $g$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,u)$ and increasing on $(u,+\infty)$ hence minimal at $u$. (Seems like a three-and-a-half-lines complete proof to me...)

Comment: Indeed @Did, this is a much more concise way to say the same thing that took me 30 lines to write... But I wanted to be sure that Di-lemma understood so I wrote it in a very detailed way, because he/she didn't understand my previous comment.

Comment: @R.Bourgeon Thanks a lot! I understand your comment now;-)